# Dynamic memory allocation in Intel Assembly on Linux with sys_brk

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, dynamic-memory-allocation, inline-assembly

So I am trying dynamic allocation of memory in C program with assembly (AT&T notation). The problem is that my allocation don't work. When I try too write a value into brk address I get segmentation fault (access violation). Also I compared brk address before and after allocation and they were the same so I guess it didn't worked. 
The information I want to add is that I want to allocate a bunch of memory pages. 
Code:

```
//...

    long int PAGE_SIZE = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE); //rozmiar strony 
    int w = 64
    int buffer_size = PAGE_SIZE * w;
    int address = 0; 

        __asm__ volatile (
            "movl $45, %%eax\n"
            "xorl %%ebx, %%ebx\n"
            "int $0x80\n"   //sys_brk - get the address of brk

            "movl %%eax, %%esi\n" //current position of brk 
            "movl %%eax, %%ebx\n"
            "addl %1, %%ebx\n" //4096(bytes)*64
            "movl $45, %%eax\n"
            "int $0x80\n" 
            "movl %%esi, %%eax\n"
            "movl %%esi, %0\n" //starting addres 
            "movl $42, (%%esi)\n"

            :"=g"(address)
            : "g"(buffer_size)
    );

//...
```

Comment: Your inline asm is not safe because you clobber a bunch of registers without telling the compiler.

Comment: Since this is 32bit code, make sure to build with `gcc -m32` if you're on a 64bit system

Comment: @NateEldredge so what should I do to make it safe, how to tell compiler about it?

Comment: Read the manual for GNU C inline asm.  Links to that + guides in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.  Don't use `asm()` unless you know exactly what you're doing.  You might want to write a stand-alone function in a `.S` file that you can `call`, if you don't know how to use clobbers and stuff like that.  Also, I'd do this with two separate `asm()` statements, each containing only the `int $0x80`, and let the compiler generate all the other instructions from pure C.

Comment: Do you really need assembly if all you want is allocate a bunch of memory?

Comment: @Steva Alekseyev - yes it's for the uni project

Comment: Without the clobbers, gcc could have picked eax or ebx to hold buffer_size.  By the time you try to use %1, who knows what it could hold?  Maybe something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/U36uts)?  Test1 is (basically) your code.  Test2b is slightly cleaner, mostly because it lets the compiler do most of the work.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I tried your inline assembly code and I still get error abut the memory access. Maybe it's about the using specific mode of running the program or just given rights to modify the memory?

Comment: Hmm. The rightmost godbolt pane shows the code actually running. If you're using Test1, what values do you get back for oldaddress & newaddress? Did you try running Test2b?  And could you be running out of memory?  The value in ebx is pretty big on godbolt.